# Itext 7 .net: filling PdfChoiceFormField

Tags: itext, itext7

I used itext5 and to fill in the values of a combo (Acroform) I used this code:

```
 formfields.SetListOption(combo, values, descriptions);
```

Now with Itext7 I'm a little bit lost, I have this: (formfields is an PdfAcroForm)

```
 formfields.GetField(combo)
```

but I can't found how to fill the combo values.

Any clues?, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a way to do it:

```
List<string> iValues = new List<string>();
// fill iValues 
PdfArray valuesArray = new PdfArray(iValores,true);
formfields.GetField(combo).SetOptions(valuesArray);
```

and it works.